# IF statement in Access Macros

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to use the Macro utility in access to run an append query if the ID key in the Parent data table is larger than the ID key in the child table, named `Hoover Data` and `Hoover Match` respectively.

My Macro has the following objects:

```
SetWarnings, No
   If Max([Hoover Data]![ID])>Max([Hoovers Match]![ID])
      OpenQuery, 'Hoovers Match Update'
      CloseWindow, 'Hoovers Match Update'
SetWarnings, Yes
```

My query, `Hoovers Match Update` runs fine and so does my Macro before I added the if statement -- that is to say that despite the shorthand writing of the above macro configuration is is correct.

When I run the macro with the if statement I receive the following error:
   Access Cannot find the name `Hoover Data` you've entered in the expression

I'm running Access 2013 (32bit) on a Win 7 (64 bit) Machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer to aggregates in external tables/queries, use the Domain Aggregate Family. Specifically for you [DMax()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dmax.php):

```
SetWarnings, No
   If DMax("ID", "[Hoover Data]") > DMax("ID","[Hoovers Match]") Then
      OpenQuery
        Query Name 'Hoovers Match Update'
   End If          
SetWarnings, Yes
```

Also, there's no need to close an action query (append/delete/update)

Comment: Thank you Parfait, I'm still transitioning from 'Excel Thinking' but this not only answered my question but raised my awareness of the Domain Aggregate Functions & the nature of launching action queries programmatically - a perfect, concise, and holistic answer, thank you.
-E